# C# Math.Sqrt() not working

Tags: c#, .net

So I am still rather new to C# programming, so I'm sure I'm making a very simple mistake here.  I am using visual studio to make a console application and in this application, I am trying to find the square root of a number.  I have the .NET framework.
Here is the top of my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Linear
{
    public static class Math
    {
        static void Main()
        {
          // program in here
        }
     }
}
```

In the program, I have a line that goes like this:

```
double distanceA = Math.Sqrt(totalA);
```

So when I build the program with VS, it tells me that 'Linear.Math' does not contain a definition for 'Sqrt'.
Why does it say this?  How can I give it a definition for 'Sqrt'?

Comment: **TL;DR** `System.Math.Sqrt(totalA);`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because you named your class `Math`, Visual Studio and the compiler do not know if you are referring to your own class (`Linear.Math`), or the .NET [`Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class (`System.Math`).

You can specify that you would like to use the *.NET* `Math` class by instead by fully qualifying the name.:

```
double distanceA = System.Math.Sqrt(totalA);
```

This specifies you would like to use `System.Math`. You can use this throughout the entire file by adding the following after your using directives:

```
using Math = System.Math;
```

This is called the *[using alias directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)*, which will tell the compiler that `Math` refers to `System.Math`.

Note that it's usually not advised to use conflicting names when creating your own classes.

Comment: @ColeZ. if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as solution.